# understanding a c #define that returns a value at a memory address

Tags: c, memory, c-preprocessor, microcontroller

This c code returns the value at a memory address.

```
value = MemoryRead((ptr))
```

`MemoryRead` is a `#define` defined as

```
#define MemoryRead(A) (*(volatile unsigned char*)(A))
```

How does this work? Could somebody explain how this returns a value at an address?

Comment: This has been asked and explain hundreds of times before. Please do some research on SO before asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(addr) returns the value stored at `addr`.

The above code looks self explanatory. If you dry run.

Consider `value = MemoryRead((ptr))`

Becomes `value = (*(volatile unsigned char*)((ptr)))`

The `#define` looks really cryptic at first. The way to understand this is by breaking it down into pieces, [as done here](https://paritycheck.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/what-does-this-mean-volatile-unsigned-char-0x22/);

> First of all,
>
> ```
> unsigned char
> ```
>
> means we are using a byte-sized memory location. Byte being 8-bits
>   wide.
>
> ```
> unsigned char *
> ```
>
> means we are declaring a pointer that points to a byte-sized location.
>
> ```
> (unsigned char *) (ptr)
> ```
>
> means the byte-sized pointer points to address `ptr`. The C compiler
>   will refer to address `ptr`. The assembly code will end up using ptr
>   in Load(LD) and Store (STR) instructions.
>
> ```
> (*(unsigned char *)(ptr))
> ```
>
> The first asterisk from the left signifies that we want to manipulate
>   the value in address `ptr`. * means “the value pointed to by the
>   pointer”.
>
> ```
> volatile
> ```
>
> volatile forces the compiler to issue a Load or Store anytime
>   `MemoryRead` is accessed as the value may change without the compiler
>   knowing it.
>
> So any address entered at `ptr` will be directly accessed by your
>   code. (If the address is present in memory.)

Comment: In future, please be sure to clearly reference your sources, per http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Comment: I did mention the source, check the history?